# Parse json array on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
[{"id":"value","first_name":"value","last_name":"value"},
 {"id":"value","first_name":"value","last_name":"value"},
 {"id":"value","first_name":"","last_name":""}]
```

Then I implement my code :

```
NSError *err;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abcd.com/index.php?r=WS/Employee"]];
NSData *dataFromUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

if (err)
    NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", err);
```

For which, I get the following error message:

> JSONObjectWithData error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "The operation couldn’t be  completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text
>   did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not
>   set.) UserInfo=0x9c900f0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Please help me to get those data.

Comment: there's something else coming with this json in response of your service..

Comment: How is the JSON created? Is it encoded using a valid JSON encoding?  UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE or UTF-32BE

Comment: I use PHP to create it.

echo "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";
        echo json_encode($r);

Comment: Try removing the meta-data tag. You should use the http header content-type instead.

Comment: I can fix this with "header('Content-type: application/json');"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix this by replace request header in my PHP file from

```
echo "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">";
```

to

```
 ob_start();
 header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u should put something more in request header. Try convert NSData to NSString and look what is comming for you

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataFromUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

And I get collect messages as I post JSON data above

Comment: try to use this library https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel They have their own built-in HTTP client.

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

```
NSURL * url =[NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
NSData * data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

json =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *err;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abcd.com/index.php?r=WS/Employee"]];
NSData *dataFromUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:     NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

if (err)
   NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData error: %@", err);
```

Just Change your line

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:     NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
```

with

```
NSJSONSerialization *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataFromUrl options:     NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)jsonData];
NSLog(@"Success:%@", array);
```